# Exibir um botão baseando na ação de outro

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Sou iniciante no asp.net MVC
Tenho um projeto.
E dentro de uma determinada view eu tenho dois botões.

Porem, um deles só pode aparecer, se o outro for executado.

1 Botão> Salvar (salva carro)
2 Botão> Associar uma concessionária (só pode estar ativado, quando eu salvar o carro)

Associar uma concessionária é uma PopUp que exibe um grid com checkbox e permite que o usuário selecione uma concessionaria para associar. Isso já funciona perfeitamente.

Podem me ajudar? 
Se precisarem de mais informações, é só falar.

Eu acredito precisar de um cód javascript na view, mas não tenho noção de como montar ele. Não tenho conhecimentos suficientes em js.

Ambos estão na mesma view.

**View**

```
@model Carro
@{
    var idConcessionaria = "id" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 5);

}
<div class="box-fields">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        "Incluir",
        "Carro",
        new DefaultAjaxOptions()
    ))
    {
        @Html.Partial("Validation")

       @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.Id)
       @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Modelo)
       @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Codigo)
        [...]



       <div class="clear">

        <div class="box-button">
            <input type="submit" class="button blue" value="@Geral.Salvar" />
        </div>


        <div id="@idConcessionaria" class="box-button">
         <a class="button blue" href="#@idConcessionaria" onclick="openPopUpConcessionaria()" >@AdicionarConcessionaria</a>
        </div>
        </div>

    }

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function openPopUpConcessionaria() {
        var newGuid = guid();
        $('#console').load('@Url.Action("SelecionarConcessionaria", "Concessionaria")');
        return false;
    }


</script>
```

**Controller Carro**

```
public ViewResultBase Salvar()
    {
        Carro model = new Carro();
        return base.SwitchView(model);
    }
[HttpPost]
[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]
public ViewResultBase Salvar([ModelBinder(typeof(CollectionModelBinder))]Carro model)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {                    
            this.Service.AddItem(model);

            return this.PopUpSuccessView();
        }
        catch (ValidationException exception)
        {
            base.AddValidationErrors(exception);
            return base.PartialView(model);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return base.PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

**Services**

```
public void AddItem(Carro item)
        {
            base.context.Carros.Add(item);
            base.Save();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o melhor caminho seria você alterar o fluxo do seu sistema de maneira que o botão Associar só fosse mostrado quando o usuário estivesse Editando um carro.

Por exemplo, crie uma Action chamada Adicionar, nesta action você retorna uma View chamada AdicionarOuEditar.cshtml (reutilizar a mesma View).

```
public ActionResult Adicionar()
{
    return View("AdicionarOuEditar");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Adicionar(SuaModelAqui model)
{
    //seu código para salvar aqui
    return RedirectToAction("Editar", new { id = seuNovoIdAqui });
}
```

Crie a respectiva Action para o seu HttpPost.

Na sua View, crie uma condição para mostrar ou não o botão, algo parecido como:

```
@if(Model != null && Model.Id != 0)
{
   significa que sua view está em modo de edição
   mostra o botão
}
```

Depois você cria uma outra action chamada Editar e segue os mesmos passos anterior, porém com códigos específicos para edição.

```
public ActionResult Editar(int id)
{
    var model = carregarSuaModelAqui(id);
    return View("AdicionarOuEditar", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Editar(SuaModelAqui model)
{
    //seu código para salvar aqui
    return Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```